# Why did my output change when I called the class attribute from an instance instead of the class?

Tags: python, class, oop, instance, class-attributes

(*I'm fairly new to programming, so understand that my query might not make sense. I've tried my best to explain it but if you are still confused, you can ask me to clarify*)

I understand the that we can call the class attribute `number_of_people` and increment by one so that when we create a new instance (in this context, a person), the number of people increases by one:

```
class Person:

     # Class attribute
     number_of_people = 0

     # Constructor
     def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        # Every time we call the constructor, we increment the number of people.
        Person.number_of_people += 1

# Driver code
p1 = Person("Jack")
print(Person.number_of_people)
# output gives 1
```

However, I'm having trouble with understanding the output of the code when we change the we choose to increment `p1.number_of_people instead` of `Person.numer_of_people`:

```
class Person:

     # Class attribute
     number_of_people = 0

     # Constructor
     def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        # Every time we call the constructor, we increment the number of people.
        p1.number_of_people += 1

# Driver code
p1 = Person("Jack")
print(p1.number_of_people)
# output gives 0 (I expected the output to be 1)
```

I thought that since class attributes can be accessed by both the class and instances, my change wouldn't make a difference. I suspect it has to do with `p1` being mentioned in the class before it's mentioned in the driver code, but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: `NameError: name 'p1' is not defined` is what I get when I try to run that. It's less about class attributes or instance-vs-class and more about variable scope. Inside of `Person` it is not aware of an instance of itself, outside of itself and so it errors. I'm not sure how you managed to get it to print `0`.

Comment: Your second version should throw a `NameError` exception: `p1` inside the class definition isn't defined?

Comment: You must have already had something else bound to `p1` when you ran the second snippet. Perhaps you ran it in the same session, after running the first snippet?

Comment: @user2357112 Ah, you're right. Just ran it in a new script and got an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the demonstration you were trying to do for yourself is to examine the difference between using the class attribute as a class attribute, vs as an instance attribute.  Consider this difference:

```
class Person:
    population = 0

    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        Person.population += 1

p1 = Person("Jack")
p2 = Person("Tom")
p3 = Person("Bill")
print(p1.population)
print(p2.population)
print(p3.population)
```

Output:

```
3
3
3
```

Compared to:

```
class Person:
    population = 0

    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        self.population += 1

p1 = Person("Jack")
p2 = Person("Tom")
p3 = Person("Bill")
print(p1.population)
print(p2.population)
print(p3.population)
```

Output:

```
1
1
1
```

In the second example, the instance starts out using the class attribute, but as soon we change it, it creates an instance attribute that has a separate life.

Comment: "each instance inherits a COPY of the class attribute" is inaccurate. Initially, when `self.population += 1` loads the `population` attribute, it loads the value from the class dict, because there's no value in the instance dict. However, when `self.population += 1` then tries to *set* the attribute to a new value, it sets the value in the instance dict, leaving the class dict untouched.

Comment: That is better wording.  I'll revise.

Comment: Right, so although the class and instance attribute both represent the same thing e.g. ```population```, they are still seperate entities.

Comment: Sort of.  They both have the same name, but they are names in different namespaces, and hence are unrelated.